# Is the Angry Birds Game and Movie on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Ok they are machine making, cowboy hat wearing, egg stealing pigs and the Birds are well you know! So I would say that they are well out of the bounds of the normal and into the world of the fantastical.

But before I ask my question I wanted to know if they were on topic or not. :)

Comment: *"they are well out of the bounds of the normal and into the world of the fantastical."* - Um, just to be sure, you know you're on *Movies & TV meta* here, right?

Comment: That being said, the movie is clearly on-topic, since it is, well, a movie. The game only partially if the actual question still relates to the movie.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I wandered onto the wrong meta... I thought this was my book mark for the SFF SE Meta... Oops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any questions about specific movies or television shows are on-topic here as long as the question is *actually about* the movie or television show. (It doesn't have to be fantastical -- even documentaries would be on-topic here.)

Questions that only relate to the game itself would not be.

Also note that our gaming site, [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), will obviously answer questions about the game, but the *also* answer questions about the game's lore. They probably would not answer a question specifically about the movie.

It's also *possible* that Angry Birds is fantasy-enough that [Sci-Fi and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) might take questions about both but it's not as clear cut as you'd think. Movies and TV is probably a safer bet.

Comment: I honestly thought that this was SFF meta... But still good to know that it is on topic here. :)